# For...in loop causing potential out-of-memory crash

Tags: javascript, out-of-memory

Let's say you have this big `array` arr.

```
var arr = new Int32Array(99999999);
```

These two for loops do different things. This one pauses for a good amount of time and eventually returns a potential out-of-memory crash:

```
for (var i in arr) {console.log("done"); break;} 
// --> Paused before potential out of memory crash.
```

While this one ends instantly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {console.log("done"); break; } 
// --> Finishes immediately.
```

I know why the 2nd loop ends instantly, but why does the first loop cause a leak?

Comment: A memory leak is something different. Anyways, this is highly implementation dependent, you should look at the V8 source to figure this out (i am assuming you tested in chrome, although you did not mention anything about that). It's likely because the head evaluation creates a list of all properties and potentially other things, which is ridiculously big again. Why this crashes for a hundred million entries already is a bit odd, but not super unexpected.

Comment: Yeah... my bad for calling it a leak. Thank you for the response, but would you know of any other way to do something like the first for loop but with an object? Lets say you have an object with 99999999 properties. Could you cycle through its properties without a memory crash?

Comment: My question would be why do you have an object with a hundred million properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard, execution of `for...in` and `for...of` statements includes a step which acquires `BoundNames` from the object.

Refer to https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements.

Here is the brief:

> BoundNames: Return a new List containing the StringValue of Identifier.

It means if you are iterating a large array, the engine must acquire a large `List` which contains all the indexes and other attributes of the array before the actual iteration happens. If the `List` is too big, you see a memory crash.

And on the other side, it doesn't include the acquiring `List` step while using index-based `for` loop.

Comment: I am still a bit confused why a list, that is "just" a hundred million entries, already causes a crash. It should only be similar in size to the actual array (indexes 0-99999998). However, i can clearly see the process go way up in memory, until it reaches the 4GB mark and crashes (almost surely because of legacy 32bit addressing of RAM, which is still prevalent in many applications). I suspect that it stores attributes of the indexes at the start (e.g. enumerability, which is relevant to `for ... in`), which are considerably larger than just the indexes.

Comment: @ASDFGerte `BoundNames` are strings instead of integer indexes, i.e.: index `99,999,998` needs `2 * 8 = 16` bytes, and other attributes created by the string instance.

Comment: that is true, while i am not certain an implementation will keep it that way internally. Anyways, it's pretty likely that list causes the issue, so there must be something about it that uses extra space in the implementation. PS: even 100,000,000 * 32 B < 4GB - standard ram usage, so there must be quite a lot of additional information.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Agree.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because `for...in` does not guarantee the return the indexes in any particular order

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index
>   order is important.